# How to use TypeVar with dictionaries

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Following is a minimal example of a class dictionary defined with keys tuples of classes, and values callables accepting instances of those classes:

```py
from typing import Callable, Dict, Tuple, TypeVar

from typing import Type

T = TypeVar("T")

A: Dict[
        Tuple[Type[T],...], Callable[[T], str]
    ] = {
        (bool, str, int, float): lambda d: str(d)
    }
```

This example brings a MyPy error: `Type variable T is unbound`.

I also tried with a `Generic` container class.

```py
from typing import Callable, Dict, Tuple, TypeVar

from typing import Generic, Type

T = TypeVar("T")
class Test(Generic[T]):
    A: Dict[
            Tuple[Type[T],...], Callable[[T], str]
        ] = {
            (bool, str, int, float): lambda d: str(d)
        }
```

From there, I am getting the error:
`error: Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "Tuple[Type[bool], Type[str], Type[int], Type[float]]": "Callable[[T], str]"; expected "Tuple[Type[T], ...]"`

Then, I tried without tuples:

```
class Test(Generic[T]):
    A: Dict[Type[T], Callable[[T], str]] = {
        bool: lambda d: str(d)
    }
```

From there, I am getting the error:
`error: Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "Type[bool]": "Callable[[T], str]"; expected "Type[T]": "Callable[[T], str]`

I proceeded by even more simplifying the case:

```
T = TypeVar("T")


class Test(Generic[T]):
    A: Dict[T, T] = {bool: bool}
```

This returns an error: `Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "Type[bool]": "Type[bool]"; expected "T": "T"`

What is the right way to define a dictionary with values types bound by the types of the keys?

Comment: This wouldn't work the way you want anyway. `T` would be bound to a single class valid for *all* entries in the `dict`, not a specific type for each key/value pair. It also wouldn't be bound to something like `TypeVar('X', bool, str, int, float)` and have the argument to your lambda be inferred to be `X`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that, I was thinking whether I could use a `TypeVarTuple`, which allows for such freedom..

Comment: I don't think so. That's intended to define variadic generics. It won't let you do per-record typing for a single `dict` value.

Comment: Yes, maybe using the hacky way of `Tuple[Unpack[TypeVarTuple]]`, but still I suppose that even this tuple would then have to be uniquely defined. Hmmm. Do you think I could use typing anyhow in such a context then?

Comment: ....Apart from the obvious solution of no dependence at all:
`A: Dict[Union[type, Tuple[type, ...], Callable[[Any], str]]  ={(bool, str, int, float): lambda d: str(d)}`

Comment: You can use your own `dict` subclass with custom `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__` and other used method to be like `__getitem__(key: T |  tuple[T, ...]) -> Callable[[T], str]`

Comment: Thank you @SUTerliakov . However, I think that instantiation of such an object would then have to be done iteratively,  and not in one go,right? I mean, first define an empty custom dictionary and then in a for-loop, update the entries... Or am I wrong on that?